# Integral that resembles an exponential integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, exponential-function

$$ I(y;c,\lambda) \equiv\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\lambda c}{x} \exp\left(-\lambda x\right)\exp\left(-\frac{c}{x}y\right)dx$$ where $c,\lambda>0$.

Q: Can this integration be made in analytic form (series are acceptable, but closed form preferred)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp\bigg(-ax-\frac bx\bigg)~\frac{dx}x~=~2K_0\Big(2\sqrt{ab}\Big),~$ for positive values of *a* and *b*. See [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more information.